# Discord Bot query message content?

Tags: python, discord.py

Discord Bot query message content?

Hi there,

I will ask in a customer event what the content of a written message is,

the current code:

```
@client.event
```

async def on_message(message) :

```
blackEmbed= discord.Embed(title = "Das ist verboten!", description = "\r Du hast ein Wort aus der Blacklist abgetippt! Bitte unterlass das in der Zukunft!")

if message.content("test") :
  message.delete
  message.send(embed = blackEmbed)
```

@client.command()

But I don't know what to use instead of message.content, because I get an error here that the str object cannot be called, help please

Comment: In the code you showed us, `message.content` is never used. Please edit your questions and include the code that uses `message.content`

Comment: I dont understand, its my first bot, the question was what to use instead of message.content to query the content

Comment: You do have to use `message.content`, but as it seems in your code you're using it wrong since you get an error. So please include the code which throws the error.